# Filter/map/lambda in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I am having some trouble with the lambda function in Python3. 
See what I did so far.

```
odd_lst = []
for n in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[n] % 2 != 0:
        odd_lst.append(lst[n]**2)
```

This is the original code. I need to replace that for loop statements with a single line code using filter() and map(). 
I tried using the following line :

```
odd_lst=list(filter(lambda x: x**2 if (x%2)!=0, lst))
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
odd_lst=list(filter(lambda x: x**2 if (x%2)!=0, lst))
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to this concept. Please show what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @smac89 It is giving a Syntax error.

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question. SyntaxError could be referring to anything

Comment: odd_lst=list(filter(lambda x: x**2 if (x%2)!=0, lst))                                                                            
                                                  ^                                                                                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That ^ is pointing to the comma just before the lst.

Comment: Please include the error in your question. As in edit your question and put the full error message you got in there

Comment: Ok. I updated the question.

Comment: Thank you. In the future when you ask a question regarding an error you are getting, remember to always include the error message you get. It makes it easier to give an answer if we know what the error is, because there are numerous possibilities for errors. In particular, `SyntaxError` in python could mean anything from bad indent to incorrect arguments, to...well whatever the python interpreter cannot understand

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is to use `filter()` and `map()` to select odd numbers from an input list, square those numbers, and produce a new list with just those squares.

So, assuming you have an input `lst` already defined, your first step is to filter out just the odd numbers:

```py
odds = filter(lambda x: x %2 != 0, lst)
```

Then you need to get the squares of these odd numbers:

```py
squares = map(lambda x: x**2, odds)
```

Then you need to put these values into a result list:

```py
odd_lst = list(squares)
```

Now you can hopefully see how to combine this all into a single line:

```py
odd_lst = list(map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x %2 != 0, lst)))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It's always good to break down a problem into small chunks rather than try to do it all in one go. The less code/logic you have going on at any one time, the easier it is to figure out what is going wrong if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, quick update, one more parenthesis needed in the final answer.

Comment: True - fixed now